# Manage versions with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I currently use these tools :

- Azure DevOps - Only for Git repositories
- Jira - To manage tasks / bugs / versions / customer requests / ...
- TeamCity - Continuous integration (build and deploy versions )

I would like to replace Jira with Azure Devops (but continue to use TeamCity for builds for now.)

I already created some teams / areas / user stories / bugs.

But I would like a simple way to handle versions. For example, I fix some bugs and release a new version using TeamCity (ex. : v3.1.1.1234 ). How can I update my user stories / bugs to say that it is fix in this version ? There is no "Fix version" field like in Jira...

Should I use "Iterations" or just "tags" ?

If I want to generate release notes for the new version (for internal use), do I have to use Azure DevOps  queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a customized field (ie.Fix version) for User Stories in azure devops. You can follow below steps:

1, Create an inherited process. (only an inherited process is allowed to create custom field)

Organization Setting--> Process under Boards--> Select the Process--> Click **3dots(...)**-->Click Create inherit process.

[image]

2, Create customized Field for the inherited processs which created above

Choose your inherited process, and then choose the Work Item Type (ie, User Story)you want to customize.

Click **New field**, type in the new field's name (ie. Fix Version) in the **Definition** section. (you can decide where the new field should locate in **Layout** section or keep the default layout).
[image]

3, Change your project process to above inherited process.

Choose the process that contains you project. Click **Projects**-->Choose your Project-->Click the **3dots**-->Click **Change Process**
[image]

You can check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process) for more information.

After you finish above steps, you will see the new field Fix Version in User Stories edit page.

If you find above steps complicated, you can just use **tags**.

Answer (score 0):

@Levi Lu-MSFT, This only lets you create field in one workitem type if you want same field in Bugs, Features, Stories it wouldn't allow, it'll throw 'Field already exists" error.

Comment: It is still the same, wouldn't allow to create same field in different work items. The only work around is to create with different name.

Comment: Found a solution for this if anyone is interested in this future, when you try to add the newly added field (Fix Version) in second work item for eg. Bug you need choose 'Use an existing field' option instead of 'Create a field' and then chose the field and place it in layout.